# Use C++11 with NaCl/PNaCl

Tags: c++11, google-nativeclient

I want test NaCl and PNaCl(next, I will use NaCL for both) with default SDK and Pepper_31.

https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/

I try adapt a old project, but this project use C++11. I add  to CFLAGS this option -std=c++11, but this option is unrecognized.

cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"

Normal, NaCl support C++11, but maybe i don't understand this chapter.

https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/reference/pnacl-c-cpp-language-support#source-language-support

After some reserch to use C++11 with NaCL, a solution is use to CFLAGS this options -std=c++0x -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__=1.

But C++11 is not completly supported and I have a lot of error (this code works with GCC 4.7.2 with -std=C++11 option).

My questions are :

1) Does NaCl support really C++11?

2) If yes, How enable C++11 with NaCl?

3) Else, this support will be released shortly(Pepper_32 maybe)?

4) Have you others soltutions?

Thank for your attention.

edit:
When I compil with default toolchain with -std=c++0x -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__=1 as option, it result this error :

src/GEP_PARSE/ParserCSV.cpp: In function 'void csvWriteFile(std::vector, std::allocator >, std::allocator, std::allocator> > >, std::allocator, std::allocator >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > > > >&, const std::string&, char)':

src/GEP_PARSE/ParserCSV.cpp:16: error: expected initializer before ':' token
src/GEP_PARSE/ParserCSV.cpp:24: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
src/GEP_PARSE/ParserCSV.cpp:24: error: expected ';' before '}' token
src/GEP_PARSE/ParserCSV.cpp:24: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
src/GEP_PARSE/ParserCSV.cpp:24: error: expected ')' before '}' token
src/GEP_PARSE/ParserCSV.cpp:24: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
src/GEP_PARSE/ParserCSV.cpp:24: error: expected ';' before '}' token

Makefile:24: recipe for target 'newlib/Release/src/GEP_PARSE/ParserCSV_x86_32.o' failed
make: *** [newlib/Release/src/GEP_PARSE/ParserCSV_x86_32.o] Error 1

Code source :
for(auto row:record)
{
...
}

Comment: Did you read their website? ["The PNaCl toolchain is based on Clang 3.3, which fully supports C++11"](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/reference/pnacl-c-cpp-language-support#source-language-support). So only real question is 2) or some other, unasked one.

Comment: You can also add a few error messages too.

Comment: Thank for your answers. It is written C++11 is supported, but when? I have edited my question to add error messages.

Comment: They use present tense, so C++11 should be **already** supported. Are you sure you are using newest version of their toolchain? Please post some error messages, they can be helpful.

Comment: So fast, I don't have the time to edit my message. Last release is pepper_31(I use), next pepper is developed, but not again stable. I will try use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've found, the x86 NaCl compilers are too old for complete C++11 support:

```
$ pwd
/home/binji/dev/testsdk/nacl_sdk/pepper_31/toolchain/linux_x86_newlib/x86_64-nacl/bin

$ ./gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.3 20130827 (Native Client r12067, Git Commit 46c2b9f0e51c734569cdd6956af695881814e7ed)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

You can compare that to this page to see which features are missing: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

The PNaCl compiler supports C++11, though: https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/reference/pnacl-c-cpp-language-support

And you can use the pnacl-translate tool to convert from a .pexe to an architecture-specific .nexe.

Note that currently PNaCl uses GCC's libstdc++, not LLVM's libc++, though this should be fixed soon. See a recent thread here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/native-client-discuss/WxRAMOO_6iE/TJw6O9JtIUsJ

Comment: Thank for your answers. But PNaCl use LLVM, because it work with this option -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__=1. I think when I have found this, I forgot to test with PNaCl toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

**Using SDK Version:** pepper_49

---

Add few more information for further searching users & might answering this post as well :

- Suggest to read [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/native-client-discuss/F8ByDJrSAlw) in their mailing list
- Try adding `-std=gnu++11` option for `CFLAGS` (instead of `-std=c++11`)
  (answered by Hua Zhang in the thread above)

#### **Extensions**

Apologize for not exhaustively test every feature in C++11, and it works for me to use *auto*, *range-based-for-loop* and *initialization list* with this option.

#### **Standard Library**

As for C++11 standard library, most of it just works even without this extra option. However, some class/function are not supported well currently (e.g. *packaged_task*, *async*, *bind*). Adding this option should work.